In Australia do automatic voice transcribers have the same legal restrictions as voice recorders?
There are various legal restrictions for recording sound and voice in Australia, e.g. in some states you cannot record without permission from all being recorded, in others you can record any conversation that you participate in.
I'm interested to know if these restrictions apply to devices that transcribe sound to text but do not actually capture the voice?
For this case, the text is being saved to a file for later reference.
If Australia as a whole is too broad, then just Victoria Australia.

In case it makes a difference: is the transcribed text being recorded/captured, or perhaps just being displayed live to one of the parties who is deaf/hard-of-hearing?

@TripeHound I updated the description, the transcribed text is being saved for later reference.

There are different laws for phone calls (The Telecommunications (Interception and Access) Act 1979) and private conversations (The Listening Devices Act 1992). Which are you asking about?

@Barmar from the point of view of someone who does not understand the law in depth, if transcribing a private conversation or a discussion is different then it would be good to understand the difference.

I gave an answer referencing the law for private conversation. I expect it's similar for telephone conversation, you should be able to look up that law.

Basically, as I understand it, transcribing is a kind of recording. The law doesn't actually go into detail about the mechanism.

The Listening Devices Act 1992 (ACT) contains the following definitions:

listening device means any instrument, apparatus, equipment or
device capable of being used to listen to or to record a private
conversation, but does not include a hearing aid.
record, in relation to a private conversation, includes a statement
prepared from such a record.

Similar definitions of "listening device" and "record" appear in the Surveillance Devices Act 2007 (NSW) and the Surveillance Devices Act 1999 (Vic).
I think a transcript produced by a device would be considered a recording, as a "statement prepared from" the original digital audio record.
Furthermore, there's the simple dictionary definition of "record" (from Merriam-Webster):

to cause (sound, visual images, data, etc.) to be registered on something (such as a disc or magnetic tape) in reproducible form

A transcription is a "reproducible form". We consider a court stenographer to be recording the testimony given.

This answer could be improved by adding the jurisdiction.  Is that the Australia Capital Territory only?

I guess so, since it has that seal on all the pages. I've updated the answer.

But "from such a record" explicitly requires a record from which it is made. And "listening" seems to implicitly require a human act of listening. It would be interesting to see what the supreme court would make of that on appeal from conviction in the magistrates court.

mmm .. perhaps I need to investigate inserting memory into hearing aids and bypass the "listening device" restriction!
